# SP13 Calendar Chrome Type Not Appearing

Tags: 2013, css, calendar

I added a calendar app and would like to change the chrome type to "Title and Border" only.  The reason is because I want to add another calendar to calendar app page as web part. Therefore, I would like to be able to distinguish between the two.  However, in calendar view the changes to the Chrome Type do not appear once "apply" and "stop editing" is selected.  The best option would be to Calendar Overlay the calendars.  However, the user wants to see both calendars on the same page.  I applied CSS scripting to "force" display the "title and border" since the Chrome Type function was not working.  The CSS applied to the web part, but disappeared after selecting "Stop Editing".  I am working on a published site, therefore, not sure what the problem may be.  Has anyone had the same experience when using an Calendar app? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can just confirm that it is not working on mysite neither. On my site even changing the setting of chrome type is not saved after "stop editing". Did not look at this before because I did not have the requirement before.

Comment: i think wort to try this and see if it fix it...http://sharepointknowledgebase.blogspot.com/2012/12/webpart-chrome-type-is-not-working-or.html